# Mono's System.Windows.Forms' OpenFileDialog won't allow me to access USB drive in OSX

Tags: c#, .net, macos, dialog, mono

I am using a code in .net to "import" or read from a usb drive and to do that I am using the OpenFileDialog.

```
        // Create an instance of the open file dialog box.
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter options and filter index.
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1

        // Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialog box.
        bool? userClickedOK = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

        // Process input if the user clicked OK.
        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {
            ....
        }
```

I am then running this on a Mac under Mono but it doesn't allow me to read from a USB drive.  I only have access to my user directory.  My account is Admin so I am not sure what it might be.

Is this just the way Mono does this or is there something I can do to access this?

Comment: what's the namespace of the OpenFileDialog class that you're using?

Comment: the namespace is System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Seems like it is a bug in Mono's implementation of System.Windows.Forms then, you should open a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ (although TBH this library is not getting many contributions lately, so your best bet is fixing the bug yourself and proposing a pull request to Mono)